# Node JS- Check if field exists in mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm not sure if I am on the right track, but this is what I have...

```
router.post('/login', function(request, response) {
    User.find({ 'username': request.body.email,'email':request.body.pwd }, function(err, user) {
    //do not know what to add here
```

I am taking `POST` data from two input fields and then using `find` command to check if this field already exists in my mongo database.

`User` is the model schema I created. It looks as so...

```
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email    : String,
    password : String,
    display  : String   
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', Schema);
```

I think I am on the right track but I am not sure what to add inside the `find` command. If both fields exist together, I want to do one thing, if they don't I want to throw an error, how can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using `findOne` over `find`, as it will return a single document if it exists, otherwise `null`.

```
router.post('/login', function(request, response) {
   // use `findOne` rather than `find`
   User.findOne({ 
    'username': request.body.email,
    'email':request.body.pwd }, function(err, user) {
      // hanlde err..
      if (user) {
        // user exists 
      } else {
        // user does not exist
      }
   })
 })
```

Comment: shouldn't there be a better way of just checking the schema for the field rather then making a call to the database to see ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using find in your query, meaning you are trying to find ALL matching users, and expecting an array of users from the mongodb.

If none found, the user variable will be an empty array.

If you just want to let the browser know that the request was fine, password matched the database record and the user was found, you can do something like:

```
router.post('/login', function(request, response) {
    User.find({ 'username': request.body.email,'email':request.body.pwd },
    function(err, user) {
    //do not know what to add here
        if (user.length === 0) {
          return response.status(403).send("Unauthorized");
        }

        return response.status(200).send("OK");
    }
```

P.S.
Also, you can use mongoose findOne query for the purpose of user login.